# how do I display both a term view and parent terms view on the same taxonomy term page

Tags: 7, views, search

I am using search api views to override core taxonomy term pages. I would like to create a view that displays parent term content as well like a related content block. Or as a view I can use when results are empty.

I am not able to achieve this so far. I have tried the Parent terms (indexed) filter using every default argument combination I can think of. I have tried the indexed taxonomy terms filter also using every default argument I could imagine. What I assumed would be a very simple views has turned out to be rather complicated. I am starting to wonder if it is actually not a configuration problem at all but related to search api and might not even be possible in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps to show **content of Parent Term on current Term**.

1. Create a view as block
2. Add relationship as **Parent Term**
3. Add contextual filter as **Term ID** using the **relationship** and set it [like this](https://snag.gy/dI8iQ3.jpg)
4. Add filter criteria as **Taxonomy Vocabulary** using the relationship
5. Add **fields** whatever you have in taxonomy and use relationship as well

You can also follow the steps in the pics I've created for you.
[image]

You don't need to create a new view to show the **content of current taxonomy**, you can set **manage display**. Go to `admin/structure/taxonomy/TAXONOMYNAME/display`

While if you want to display using view, then create another view and follow these steps:

1. Add contextual filter as **Term ID** and set it [like this](https://snag.gy/dI8iQ3.jpg)
2. Add fields of the taxonomy you want to show

*Note that we won't use any relationship in this view*

Now, go to in the block configuration `admin/structure/block` and enable these.

I hope this will work for you

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. unfortunately, my view uses search api indexed fields and it does not appear that some of your filters and relationships are available.